# Impossible to set the gamma parameter for the spectral_clustering function in sklearn 0.18.1

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, spectral

I am doing some clustering using the scikit-learn (aka sklearn) and everything worked fine until I tried to play with the `gamma` parameter of the `spectral_clustering` function.

I am using sklearn (0.18.1) with python (3.5.2) in a virtual environment manage with anaconda (1.5.1).

In the [official documentation of the function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering.html#sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering), there is mention of a parameter `gamma` :

> class sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering(n_clusters=8, eigen_solver=None, random_state=None, n_init=10, **gamma=1.0**, affinity='rbf', n_neighbors=10, eigen_tol=0.0, assign_labels='kmeans', degree=3, coef0=1, kernel_params=None, n_jobs=1)

However, on my machine when I try to pass the parameter `gamma` to the function, I get the following error:

> TypeError: spectral_clustering() got an unexpected keyword argument 'gamma'

And then, when I display the help page of the function `help(spectral_clustering)`, I got completely different information than on the [official documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering.html#sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering) :

> spectral_clustering(affinity, n_clusters=8, n_components=None, eigen_solver=None, random_state=None, n_init=10, eigen_tol=0.0, assign_labels='kmeans')

It is like some parameters are mising. I thought maybe it is coming from the conda package but installing it with pip doesn't solve the problem.

I even tried to install it outside of a virtual environment and still a similar problem.

However, I asked two of my colleagues and one had the same problem as me while the other one could see the same information in the `help(spectral_clustering)` function as in the official documentation.

How can I get the same functionalities as in the official documentation?

I am using the `spectral_clustering` function in one of my pipeline as the following:

```
if clt_mtd == 'spectral':
    # Spectral clustering
    labels = spectral_clustering(sm, n_clusters=num_clt, random_state=seed, gamma=0.1)
```

This function is working perfectly fine as long I don't try to modify the `gamma` parameter.

---

**Solved:** 
My mistake is coming from [one of the official example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_segmentation_toy.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-segmentation-toy-py) that I used as a reference.

**Solution:**
As discussed in the commentaries below, `SpectralClustering` and `spectral_clustering` are not the same. The last one is used by the function `fit` in the class `SpectralClustering` and doesn't take `gamma` as a parameter as this one is used before in the function `fit`.

Therefore, to be able to modify the `gamma` parameter one should instantiate a `SpectralClustering` object first and use the function `fit` provided by this class.

Comment: There is the class ```SpectralClustering``` and there is the function ```spectral_clustering```. The latter is used internally and corresponds to your help call. Show the code of what you are doing exactly. (Actually it already looks like you are calling the function with the gamma-param which is wrong. You have to call the class and later fit, like always in sklearn!)

Comment: @sascha : I added an Edit with the way I am using the function. So if I understand correctly what you are saying, I can't really modify gamma from the function call because it is not a parameter of the function `spectral_clustering` but a parameter of the class `SpectralClustering`. Is it correct ?

Comment: Just follow the docs and use the class-based SpectralClustering, where the gamma is part of the docs.

Comment: @sascha, thanks a lot, you are absolutely right. I checked in the source code and the function `spectral_clustering` is used by the function `fit` of the class `SpectralClustering` but without the `gamma` parameter as it is used previously in the function `fit`.